# Cannot find or load main class com.yahoo.ycsb.Client

Tags: ycsb

I'm trying to create a custom database binding, FooStore, for YCSB.  I've compiled this via

```
mvn -pl com.yahoo.ycsb:foostore -am package
```

to a jar file, which I've tried to add to the classpath [per Step 7](https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB/wiki/Adding-a-Database)

```
java -cp lib/foostore-0.13.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.yahoo.ycsb.Client 
  -load -db com.yahoo.ycsb.db.FooStoreClient -P workloads/workloada
```

which I'm executing from the ycsb-0.12.0 directory (with my new jar file in the `lib` directory), which results in

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.yahoo.ycsb.Client
```

Where should I be executing the `java` command from, and/or which jar(s) do I need to add to my classpath in order to fix this command?

---

Alternatively, how do I modify YCSB so that I can recompile it via `mvn package` and then simply execute `./bin/ycsb load foostore -P workloads/workloada`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to add a database keyword in `ycsb`?

1. Maven gave you a `ycsb-foostore-binding-0.13.0-SNAPSHOT.tar.gz`. Untar it (in another directory).
2. Edit `ycsb-foostore-binding-0.13.0-SNAPSHOT/bin/ycsb` and edit the `DATABASES` dictionary by adding a line like:

   ```
   "foostore" : "com.yahoo.ycsb.db.FooStoreClient",
   ```
3. Run your custom YCSB:

   ```
   cd ycsb-foostore-binding-0.13.0-SNAPSHOT/
   /bin/ycsb load foostore -thread 1 -P workload/worloada -s
   ```